# Reinstalling default ruby on Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ruby

I am using the directions given here: http://blog.bloople.net/read/104 and i am stuck at the second terminal command. i modified it to make RC_ARCHS=i386 SYSSTRING=universal-darwin10.5.0 and i recieve make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

what can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't cd into the directory that you expanded.

On my system the terminal command would be:

cd ~/Downloads/ruby-75

Comment: i did do that, though the directory name was different... ~/Downloads/ruby-1.8.7-p174

Comment: well, this was technically the correct answer. i downloaded the incorrect ruby tar